# plus sign in URL transfers to space

Tags: javascript, gwt, xmlhttprequest

Although i encode the plus sign to %2B, the server reads it as space.
I send the request using javascript XMLHttpRequest.

Why it happens?

Comment: *How* do you 'encode the plus sign'? *Show us* your *code*.

Comment: As i said, i encode it to %2B. I run my own algorithm. Also tried using URL.encode and URL.encodeQueryString with same result (GWT)

Comment: So show us your 'own algorithm.' Presumably you've tried [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)?

Comment: Perhaps it is a server-side issue — can you verify what is actually sent on the wire, `' '`, `'+'`, or '`%2B`'?

Comment: What are you running on the server? The `+` sign is commonly used in place of spaces, this suggests that your query string is being decoded twice on the server. Check the *Net* panel on your browser's inspector too to make sure GWT isn't decoding it before actually sending the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encoding/Decoding is not a fancy thing. The fundamentals are simple. Thus as long as you encode/decode via a **single** algorithm, then you have to get to the original text.

Maybe something is wrong in your **decoding algorithm**.

I recommend that you install [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/), and see what goes out of your client computer. You might also log the very first arrival of the request by your web server to see what you get there.

Comment: `The fundamentals are *simple.`

Comment: You mean *decoding* algorithm